# Not able to delete Keyword related to old versions using Tridion core service

Tags: core-service, 2013-sp1-hr1

How to delete keyword which is being used in old versions of component using core service, The keyword was earlier used in few components.How to fetch versions of components in which the keyword was used using core service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from deleting a Keyword that is only used in old versions of other items. You are only prevented from deleting it if current versions refer to it.

So the real answer is to just call the `Delete` method.

That said, if you want to use the Core Service to find out the items that are using your Keyword, you need to use one of the list-related methods (e.g. `GetList`) and pass in a `UsingItemsFilterData` object as the filter.